# Elm Signals in Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, signals, elm

I know it's possible to implement signals / observables / streams in vanilla JS, because Elm compiles back to JS.

Can anyone off an example of a signal translated to JS? It must use a callback structure right? For example, what does Elm translate this to?

```
    main =
       Signal.map show Mouse.position
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a very crude way you could think of this as equivalent to:

```
document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;

function handleMouseMove(event) {
    //...extract x and y from event somehow
    show([x, y])
}
```

But there is a lot more happening in Elm, it is a lot more similar to observable objects in RXjs https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md

Comment: Hey Sebastian, thanks for the answer. My question is really more general - how are these reactive structures (Signals, Observables, Streams, whatever...) handled in vanilla JS? What's the central JavaScript core of them? I feel like this is missing from any descriptions I've seen, and they feel like magic.

Comment: Your question is far too broad to be answered succinctly on StackOverflow. I think Sebastian gave the best answer you'll get for how you can reason about Elm, but if you truly want to understand the Elm runtime then here is the paper that the creator, Evan Czaplicki wrote for his thesis https://www.seas.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/files/archived/Czaplicki.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The simple code you put does not translate to a simple callback structure in JS. The Elm runtime is a little bit more complex than that. However, if you really want to get a better understanding, you can take a look at the [Native implementation of Signal](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/master/src/Native/Signal.js).

Comment: Does that mean there is no straightforward mental model of reactive structures like Signals, Observables, Streams, whatever in pure JavaScript? Are these structures all intrinsically complex, lacking analogue in vanilla JS?

In other words, looking at the native implementation you linked to, which parts of this code are the absolutely essential bits that make the skeleton of Signals possible?

Comment: It's the basic observable pattern. A signal is a value over time. This means that you need to maintain a list of observers and inform them when the value changes. Maybe this will help: https://carldanley.com/js-observer-pattern/